# Why is there no option to mark a question solved when I got the answer from a comment?

Tags: feature-request

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Java- PrepareRenderer not giving object Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006112/java-preparerenderer-not-giving-object-data)*

I have asked this question some time ago, and thanks to this very helpful community, I got an answer for my question by a comment, not an answer, so I was trying to find a way to show other users that this problem is solved even it has no direct answers. Don't you think this could be helpful for others?

Answer (score 5):

There are two options here:

1. Post a comment asking the author of the answer-comment to convert it to a proper answer.
2. If it fails, do it yourself. Mark it as "Community Wiki".

Comment: In general, I agree. In the specific case, the answer is probably posted as a comment because almost all question which basically are "Here is some code, I have a NullPointerException" get closed against [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Why Community Wiki? To avoid downvotes from reputation points envy users?

Comment: Because technically it is other user work, so if you post it as an answer your not really deserve all upwotes.